# Hashing a string using a passphrase in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, encryption, hash

I need a way of hashing a existing filename with a passphrase (ASCII string) but being able to revert it back afterwards using the same passphrase.

I know that ciphers can do this - they are encrypting the string... But their output lenght is based on the filename lenght, which is exactly what I do not want... mainly because it sometimes doubles the file lenght, but the outputted strings are not allways compatible with the FS. Ex. "\n" in a filename.

To be clear, I did a lot of research and even wrote some scripts, but all of the solutions are either slow, or don't work for my application at all.

**The Goal of this** is to get a constant length filenames that can be all 'decrypted' at once using a single passphrase. Without the need of creating additional 'metadata-like' files.

Comment: If it's reversible at all, it's not a cryptographic hash. That's not how they work / what they do / what they're for.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know that, I mentioned that Ciphers are exactly for this. But I need some of the properties of hashes - like constant hash lenght, speed, etc.

Comment: (Now, I suppose you could store some content xor'd with the output of a cryptographic hash -- it sounds a little bit like that might be what you want -- but if you described your goal in more detail, you're likely to get a better suggestion).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I updated the question, with what I think currently are my goals.

Comment: That's still quite hand-wavey. Please try to make it concrete. **Why** do you have that goal? What are the actual constraints guiding your design decisions?

Comment: (BTW, every character other than the NUL byte and `/` is permitted in typical UNIX filesystems' filenames; a newline is completely legal).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, I see that too. The thing is, I do not even really know where to start. I imagine what I need like a 2-key algorithm. One key is the hash, the second is my passphrase, and when you combine them, you get the filename.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124834/discussion-between-areuz-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: It sounds like you really want is [Format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten all the way around with my initial question. There seems to be only one solution to the problem above, and that is (as James suggested) Format-preserving encryption. Altough, as far as I can tell, there are no existing commands that do this.

So I did exactly what was my very first option, and that is hashing the filename, putting the hash and the filename into a plain file (one file per directory) and encrypting that file with a passphrase.

I'll post my code here. Though it's probably not the prettiest nor the most portable code, but It does the job and is (IMO) really simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

man="Usage:  namecrypt [ -h ] [ -e || -d ] [ -F ] [ -D ] [DIRECTORY] [PASSPHRASE]\n
    -h, --help      display this message

    -e, --encrypt       encrypt the specified directory
    -d, --decrypt       decrypt the specified directory

    -F, --files     include files
    -D, --dir       include directories

    [DIRECTORY]     relative or absolute path to a directory/symbolic link
    [PASSPHRASE]        optional - specify the user passphrase on command line";

options=();
for Arg in "$@"; do
    if [ "$Arg" == "-h" ] || [ "$Arg" == "--help" ]; then
        echo -e "$man"; exit; 
    elif [ "$Arg" == "-e" ] || [ "$Arg" == "--encrypt" ]; then
        options[0]="E";
    elif [ "$Arg" == "-d" ] || [ "$Arg" == "--decrypt" ]; then
        options[0]="D";
    elif [ "$Arg" == "-F" ] || [ "$Arg" == "--files" ]; then
        options[1]="${options[1]}F";
    elif [ "$Arg" == "-D" ] || [ "$Arg" == "--dir" ]; then
        options[1]="${options[1]}D";
    elif [ -d "$Arg" ]; then
        options[2]="$(realpath "$Arg")";
    else    
        options[3]="$Arg";      
    fi;
done;

if [ "${options[0]}" == "" ]; then echo "No Mode specified!"; exit 1; fi;
if [ "${options[1]}" == "" ]; then options[1]="F"; fi;
if [ "${options[2]}" == "" ]; then echo "No such directory!"; exit 2; fi;
if [ "${options[3]}" == "" ]; then echo "Enter a passphrase: "; read options[3]; fi;

shopt -s nullglob dotglob;

function hashTarget
{
    BASE="$(basename "$1")";
    DIR="$(dirname "$1")/";

    if [ -a "$1" ]; then
        oldName="$BASE";
        newName=$(echo "$oldName" | md5sum);
        echo "$oldName||$newName" >> "$DIR.names";
        mv "$1" "$DIR$newName";
    else echo "Skipping '$1' - No such file or directory!";
    fi;
}

function dehashTarget
{
    BASE="$(basename "$1")";
    DIR="$(dirname "$1")/";

    [ -f "$DIR.names.cpt" ] && ccdecrypt -K "${options[3]}" "$DIR.names.cpt";

    if [ -f "$DIR.names" ]; then
        oldName="$BASE";
        newName=$(grep "$oldName" "$DIR.names" | awk -F '|' '{print $1}');
        [[ ! -z "${newName// }" ]] && mv "$1" "$DIR$newName";
    else
        echo "Skipping '$1' - Hash table not found!";
    fi;
}

function mapTarget
{   
    DIR="$(dirname "$1")/";

    for Dir in "$1"/*/; do
        mapTarget "$Dir";
    done;

    for Item in "$1"/*; do
        if ([ -f "$Item" ] && [[ "${options[1]}" == *"F"* ]]) || 
           ([ -d "$Item" ] && [[ "${options[1]}" == *"D"* ]]); then

            if [ "${options[0]}" == "E" ]; then
                hashTarget "$Item";
            else
                dehashTarget "$Item";
            fi;
        fi;
    done;

    [ "${options[0]}" == "D" ] && [ -f "$DIR.names" ] && rm "$DIR.names";
    [ "${options[0]}" == "E" ] && [ -f "$DIR.names" ] && ccencrypt -K "${options[3]}" "$DIR.names";

}

mapTarget "${options[2]}";
```

Probably the only reason why it is so long, is because I didn't bother with any OOP, and I also did a lot of checks and steps to make sure that most of the time no names get mangled and can't be restored - user error can still cause this.

This is the command used to encrypt the hash-table files: [CCrypt](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Any changes or comments about the code are, of course, welcome. I'm not really a skilled bash programmer.

Comment: That is a pretty good solution! That is what I meant with building a hash table :-)

Comment: @mahatmanich Thank you! I JUST reposted a completely new code, the old one was buggy and had limitations like spaces in directory names, and didn't do some specific error checks.

Comment: md5 should suffice, but be aware of collisions. But it should not pose any problems I think.

Comment: @mahatmanich It should be fine, in real applications Hash collisions are really really unlikely. Also the hash-tables are generated per-directory, which notably decreases the chances.